uninstalling GNOME via tasksel broke debian
So, just few days ago I installed debian to a laptop. During setup I chose GNOME as desktop environment but I later came to the conclusion that I didn't really want a desktop. So I tried to uninstall it. I ran sudo tasksel, unchecked "Desktop Environment: GNOME" and selected OK. It did something... Can't remember the output but it was not obvious.
After that sudo and reboot were not recognized as valid commands anymore. I could reboot by executing /sbin/reboot as root though. After that, I was still greeted by GNOME and sudo and reboot were still broken. tasksel showed no desktop selected.
Long story short: It failed uninstalling GNOME and messed up my system.
I don't know what it all messed up so I consider just completely reinstalling debian again.
But I really want to understand what I did wrong. Whenever I touch Linux I mess it up pretty quick :/

The fact that Gnome was not uninstalled afterwards means that, well it wasn't uninstalled. That might be because the uninstallation had a problem; or it might be because you have other software manually installed depending on Gnome, so it couldn't be uninstalled.

Add the output of which sudo to your question.

@eyoung100 it's none. no output. same for reboot. for which su it's /usr/bin/su. Also $PATH is fine (/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games)

What happens with su - && apt install sudo?  Looks like we have to rebuild what you took out then properly remove the Desktop Environment.

great, I installed sudo again and it works. reboot can still not be found. The point of my question is - what when wrong in general? I didn't do anything besides unselecting GNOME. I didn't install and uninstall a ton of packages in between. The system was installed just a few days ago. I really only installed docker.

Is there a systemctl reboot?  I can't answer what went wrong in general, as tasksel was in charge of the removal.  I don't know why sudo was removed, but I can tell you Debian now uses SystemD so the old reboot doesn't work.  SeeUnable to shutdown / reboot my Debian 10 server

@eyoung100 no, reboot still works. It’s part of the systemd-sysv package.

@xsrf if reboot is missing, install the systemd-sysv package. As eyoung100 says, you can also reboot with systemctl reboot.

@xsrf once you get the missing reboot reinstalled as Stephen and I have alluded to we can determine how to proceed.  The object here is to have a sanely installed system with all the pieces that are expected to be there before we start removing or readding parts of GNOME etc as that only makes the issue worse.

I just formatted and reinstalled. I didn't want to repair a system with unknown issues. Still don't know what I did wrong though...
